# Send Cell Data to Custom Function in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i made a simple substring checker for a cell... 
in sheet i add formula '=searchCode(B2)'

now on Google App Script, i add this code

```
function searchCode(theData) {
  if(theData.indexOf("BP1")>0){
   return "found";
       }else{
   return "not Found";
  }

}
```

The problem App Script return error "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined. I'm thinking google sheet send B2 Cell as Object and not just regular cell

Any idea on how to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: It would only mean that you're calling there function without `theData`. Nothing else.

Comment: Thank you, it return error on the App Editor, but it actually work in Google Sheet itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found it works via Google Sheet, it return error when i test it in the Apps Editor.

Lesson Learned